# Tracking User Actions on Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, tracking

Users will each have a user profile, and he wants each user to know who has viewed their profile.  The only way I can think of doing this involves doing a database INSERT every time someone views a profile page (probably using an Ajax call at the end of the page).  This sounds like a massive performance issue, especially if the site builds up to any significant traffic.

Any ideas on how to achieve this in a performant way, or is it just the nature of tracking this kind of thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. Why add another ajax call to view?
   Do it When you call the user profile show action.. in the controller
2. Queue it to a background job (example: [starling + workling](http://www.scribd.com/doc/6134982/Starling-Workling-Simple-Distributed-Background-Jobs-With-Twitters-Queuing-System-Presentation))
3. Dont use acid DB for the viewed data, use some kind of key-value store db (cassandra, redis etc)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MySQL, I'm a big fan of using the "INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY" feature which allows you to perform an update on a row if there's a key conflict. This means that instead of one row per profile view, there could be one row per user + profile pair, or for even more granularity, user + profile + day.

Depending on your traffic situation and choice of DB engine, this may work very well even for extended periods of time. Although there may be a very large number of rows in a tracking table like this, the content is very small, like a pair of ID fields and a numeric counter, which is on the order of 12-16 bytes per entry.

For example, a tracking table might be defined as:

```
def self.up
  create_table :user_profile_views do |t|
    t.integer :user_id
    t.integer :profile_user_id
    t.integer :count, :default => 0
  end

  add_index :user_profile_views, [ :user_id, :profile_user_id ], :unique => true
end
```

For the model:

```
def self.record_view_profile!(user, profile)
  connection.execute(sanitize_sql([ "
    INSERT INTO user_profile_views (user_id, user_profile_id, count)
      VALUES (%d,%d,1)
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       count=count+1
  ", user.id, profile.id ])
end
```

This will either insert a row, or update the count for an existing row.

Comment: This solution would limit the size of the table being modified, but it would not be a terribly effective method to do auditing. You have to do a select and then either an insert or update, so your table would require better indexing on the foreign keys. Also, you lose information like the timestamp of the visit.